# Trying to find 1960s comic about another planet

Tags: story-identification, comics, space, planets

I remember reading a comic book in the 1960s about people (maybe a family?) visiting another planet, whose original inhabitants had used up the planet's oceans by using the hydrogen for propulsion to move the planet throughout space.  The family finds no living inhabitants but finds the equipment still functioning, including small circular open-air flying platforms with railings.

This has bothered me for years, unable to remember anything else about this, but the artwork of the family flying one of the platforms is stuck in my head. Any information greatly appreciated. Thank you! Rick Trilling

Answer (score 3):

This cover for Space Family Robinson # 14, October 1965, shows a rectangular platform with railings.  It is on the ground but maybe it flew since it doesn't seem to have wheels.

http://www.lostintoys.com/museum/goldkey3.html[1](http://www.lostintoys.com/museum/goldkey3.html)